# SQL... Get Value from Field based on Max value of Another Field

Tags: sql, coldfusion

Having a complete SQL mental lapse today and can't figure this out.
ColdFusion and MS Access

I'm looking to do a Query of Query in ColdFusion.

Original query:

```
<cfquery name="myQuery" datasource="xxx">
SELECT Name, ID, tblLoc.Directions, tblLoc.LocationOrder
FROM myTable 
WHERE .....             
ORDER BY tblLoc.LocationOrder
</cfquery>
```

I want to create another query from this query where I retrieve Directions where LocationOrder is max.

Thus, if myQuery returned:

```
Name       ID        Directions      LocationOrder
AA         10         AAAAAA            1
BB         11         BBBBBB            2

My QoQ would return:

Directions
BBBBBB
```

But every iteration of a seemingly simple SQL I've tried fails. I must be half-asleep or something.

```
<cfquery name="latestDirections" dbtype="query">
SELECT Directions
FROM myQuery
WHERE LocationOrder=(select max(LocationOrder) from myQuery)
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="latestDirections" dbtype="query">
SELECT Directions, MAX(LocationOrder) as maxLocationOrder
FROM get_sel_locations
</cfquery>
```

nope... neither will do it.

Comment: Your first one looks like it should work. `SELECT Directions FROM myQuery WHERE LocationOrder=(select max(LocationOrder) from myQuery)`

Comment: I agree but I get this error:  Query Of Queries syntax error.
Encountered "LocationOrder = ( select. Incorrect conditional expression, Expected one of [like|null|between|in|comparison] condition,

Comment: QoQ do not support that type of subquery. They are in memory (not database) queries and *only* support the syntax listed in the documentation. http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/using_recordsets_3.html.

Comment: Look at Yisroel's suggestion. Assuming LocationOrder is unique, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

> ...The second, "Column
>   get_sel_locations.Directions is
>   invalid in the SELECT list clause
>   because it is not contained in an
>   aggregate function and there is no
>   GROUP BY clause"

The error is pretty clear. You are missing the GROUP BY clause. When using aggregates like MAX() you have to [GROUP](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) the results by any non-aggregated columns. In this case: Directions

```
SELECT Directions, MAX(LocationOrder) as maxLocationOrder
FROM get_sel_locations
GROUP BY Directions
```

**Update** But if just you want the maximum for *everything*, then Yisroel's query is probably what you want.

**Update** As mentioned in the comments, QoQ are *not* database queries. They only support the functions/syntax listed in the documentation http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/using_recordsets_3.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, ID, tblLoc.Directions, tblLoc.LocationOrder 
FROM myTable  
WHERE .....              
ORDER BY tblLoc.LocationOrder DESC LIMIT 1;
```

should do you.  Your Directions at max LocationOrder is taken care of by sorting and limiting.

Comment: You are suggesting a new cfquery and not a query of my original query?  I need the original query as-is... can't change that to add this 'order by .... limit 1'  clause.  But I want to just retrieve a subset from that query (directions where location order is max).

Comment: @stuttsdc: If you have to query twice, my query will be a lot more efficient than a subquery.  But even more efficient is to just use your original query, sorted by LocationOrder (either ASC or DESC) and extract Directions at max LocationOrder in your application layer- you already know that either the 1st row or the last row returned (depending on your sort)  contains your desired value.

Comment: My apologies.  I'm clearly confused.  Why would a second query be faster than a QoQ?  Regardless, I'm trying to picture how I'd pull out directions where location order is max in my app layer.  It would obviously be the location in the last row of my query since I have myquery ordered by locationorder.  But the cf code for just taking the last direction returned (put into a variable w/cfset?) is not clear.  Run a loop?

Comment: @stuttsdc: QoQ, ie a subquery, is a more complex query than the simple query I've posted.  So, if you run your original query and then you run a QoQ you've spent more time than if you just run your original query and then my simple query.

Comment: @stuttsdc: Regarding how to treat the last row as different in your application- I've made the perhaps incorrect assumption that your application is already looping through your result set in order to display it somehow. I'm not a coldfusion person, so I can't give you a code example, but it should be possible to catch the last row as you exit that loop.

Comment: @dnagirl... no, your assumption is correct.  I'm doing just that.  I just gotta figure out a cf way to get at that record.  Some loop, no dobut.

Comment: @stuttsdc: what if you make your QoQ something like `SELECT Directions from myquery ORDER BY myquery.LocationOrder DESC LIMIT 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, if I understand the question correctly:

SELECT x FROM table_name WHERE y = (SELECT MAX(y) FROM table_name)

Comment: I can try this but I'm looking to do a query or a query, so 'table_name' needs to be the name of the original query.  I've tried this above (in my post and in the comments above) and I get an error: Query Of Queries syntax error.
Encountered "LocationOrder = ( select. Incorrect conditional expression, Expected one of [like|null|between|in|comparison] condition,

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you eliminate the ORDER BY clause from myQuery? Also, say how the query fails. What results are you getting?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with myQuery.  I need that query as-is, since I'm using the results elsewhere. I'm looking to run a query of that query. So, the original query works just fine.  I don't get any results with either of the other queries as written above.  with the first one, I simply get an error "LocationOrder = ( select. Incorrect conditional expression, Expected one of [like|null|between|in|comparison] condition,".  The second, "Column get_sel_locations.Directions is invalid in the SELECT list clause because it is not contained in an aggregate function and there is no GROUP BY clause"

Comment: I didn't say or imply there was anything "wrong" with myQuery; I asked what happens if you eliminate the order by clause. The errors you're getting seem spurious and I wanted to see if the order by had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the error you're getting, you might try this:

```
-- remove the parentheses
WHERE LocationOrder=select max(LocationOrder) from myQuery
```

or

```
-- use IN instead of equals even though your subquery returns a single scalar value and '=' should be fine.
WHERE LocationOrder  IN (select max(LocationOrder) from myQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first do a QoQ to get the max location

```
<cfquery name="maxDirections" dbtype="query">
  SELECT max(LocationOrder) as maxLocation 
  FROM myQuery
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="latestDirections" dbtype="query">
  SELECT Directions
  FROM myQuery
  WHERE LocationOrder = '#maxDirections.maxLocation#'
</cfquery>
```